# Spring Batch Processor issue

Tags: spring-batch, pojo

I am using spring batch to read data from excel file and process the data. In reader part, I am reading all sheet data and setting into one pojo. I need to pass that single pojo to processor component but I am getting the list of that pojo in processor. Someone face such kind of issue? Then please help.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what is the situation without seeing the actual code...

Comment: Please read about creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people help you…